# How to add if condition inside eloquent laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and this code work properly without `if` conditions, when i try to add it i got errors and this message appear :

> syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) OR  syntax error, unexpected '->'
>   (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

any help please?

```
   $moviesearch = DB::table('movies')
     -> join('qualities', 'movies.mov_ID', '=', 'qualities.mov_ID')
     -> join('genres', 'movies.mov_ID', '=', 'genres.mov_ID')
         if (isset($age)) {
             ->where('movies.name', '=', '1')
         }
         if (isset($jkk)) {
             ->where('qualitie.link', '=', '233')
         }
     ->get();

 echo json_encode($moviesearch);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following

```
$query = DB::table('movies')
     ->join('qualities', 'movies.mov_ID', '=', 'qualities.mov_ID')
     ->join('genres', 'movies.mov_ID', '=', 'genres.mov_ID');
if (isset($age)) {
    $query->where('movies.name', '=', '1');
}
if (isset($jkk)) {
    $query->where('qualitie.link', '=', '233');
}
$moviesearch= $query->get();

echo json_encode($moviesearch);
```

I hope this works for you

Comment: Thank you sir its work ,another question please i want to add ->distinct where i can place it please ?

Comment: you will need to change to `DB::table('movies')->distinct()`

Comment: and with `DB::table('movies')->select( DB::raw('DISTINCT(movies.mov_ID)') )` ? you will need to add a group by maybe

Comment: it work now thanks but it show me only one column movies.mov_ID , i want the entire row columns , i tried something like DISTINCT(*) but i got errors

Comment: I found it  ->select( DB::raw('movies.*') ) and   $moviesearch= $query->groupBy('movies.mov_ID')->get(); Thank you so much sir :)